# Getting Inner Div Container ID Dynamically

Tags: css, layout, html, drag-and-drop

If you have two divs. The main 'div 1' (yellow) is the container, while the inner 'div'(blue) id is generated dynamically, e.g.

[image: layout]

How can you get the id of the dynamically generated div?

Answer (score 1):

```
    var inner_divs=document.getElementById("div1_id").getElementsByTagName("div");
    if (inner_divs)
          var inner_div_id = inner_divs[0].id;
```

Comment: Ough.. Sorry. It seems you need CSS selector, not JavaScript code. I've overlooked this.